# .jff File Conversion OSX

Tags: macos, file, file-conversion

I've been scowering the internet for a good portion of the morning trying to figure this out:

Using OSX, is there a way to either 1) Open a .jff file directly using a third-party software or 2) Is there any terminal command that has proven successful in converting such a file to a type recognizable to OSX?

Comment: What application is that supposed to be used for? I've never heard of a JFF file, and fileext is showing it as either a JPEG image, a data file for a defunct screen reader called JAWS for Windows, or some other type of file for a program called FileViewPro.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja, the files I'm specifially trying to open are for a program called JFLAP, used in demonstrating concepts for discrete mathematics. I believe the files fall into the latter category you mentioned of being some other file type for Windows, as JFLAP is supposed to be compatible with windows or mac. The files themselves are named in a convention that makes me think they are demo's or examples of how to think about certain problems, thus being able to open them would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I think the answer is just to fill out the form [here](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/log/form.php) and download an OSX copy of JFLAP, and use that. If it's a proprietary file type, then the first answer for opening it is to use the program that it's made for. However, you could also try opening it in a text editor and seeing if it's human-readable text, or in an archive viewer to see if it's a zip archive, tarball, or some other archive file.

Comment: After looking at the JFF files accessible [here](http://www.jflap.org/samplefiles.html), they look like human-readable XML files containing an object-model for the JFLAP visual editor. Crack open your favorite plain-text editor and bust them open to look at the gooey goodness inside.

Answer (score 0):

@ShotgunNinja, you're correct on filling out the form. Thank you so much!